# Как загрузить в GoogleSheets картинку с ПК через скрипт?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть задача дублировать действие из меню "Вставка-Изображение-Вставить изображение в ячейку" в Гугл таблицах по кнопке (то есть чтобы пользователь не три раза кликал, переходя в меню, а один раз в нужной ячейке). Необходимо написать скрипт с этим действием, я нашла как подгружать картинку по URL, а как быть, если картинка на локальной машине расположена?

```
const image = SpreadsheetApp
    .newCellImage()
    .setSourceUrl('https://...')
    .build();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
    .setValue(image);
```